# TFS Branch Merging on two repositories

Tags: tfs

We have three different projects using the same sql server database. So the applications are designed in such a way that there are three web projects and one class library project (core i.e the ORM entity framework and business logic). Each of the web project solution consumes this core project. On TFS, we have four different repository for each one of this.

Now we need to enhance one of the web project and the corresponding business layer changes in core class library. As all of these applications are in production, we decided to branch the code to develop this enhancement while supporting the current production issues.

So we branched the webproject repository to have Main branch for production support issues and Dev branch for enhancements. We followed the same branching convention in Core class library project. The VS solution in each branch is referencing the core project / dll at differnt locations. The merge is creating unnecessary conflicts.

[image: click here]

Could anyone please advise what is the best way to achieve branching in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Since the web project reference to the core project, core project should be updated before web project. Once the Dev branch of core project done, you can merge it to the Main branch. So you don't need to reference Dev branch core project, you just need to make both Main and Dev branches of the web project reference to the Main branch of core project.

Actually, we suggest you [build a nuget package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) for the core project and [publish it to nuget.org](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/publish-a-package). Then in web project you would use Manage Nuget packages to install the core dlls and it will install the version you choose of the core dlls.

Comment: Core is like a business layer. As i am designing the presentation layer, the business logic needs to be written in core. Also when i am writing the business logic for the Dev branch, there can be database change. So we do not want either Dev branch code of Core or Webproject to go to prod while support issue fixes are deployed. 
The Merge conflict is due to the core dll path (the way core dll is reference in either branches of webproject) in the webproject.csproj file.

Comment: Any other expertise advice on this please?

Comment: How about publishing Main and Dev core projects as separate packages to your network share?

Comment: I don't understand this, can you please elaborate how to do it?

Comment: Instead of reference core projects, you could build a nuget package for the core project and publish it. Then web project will restore the package during build. In this way, you should not get conflict of core dll path. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget

Comment: Not sure if publishing the dll to nuget would be a feasible idea here for now. What about the network share you mentioned? In either way, the core development should be completed before the enhancing the webproject is it? Both the projects cannot be simultaneously developed in this scenario?

Comment: You could publish your package to a network share if you don't want to publish it to Nuget server: https://blog.nuget.org/20150922/Accelerate-Package-Source.html. The webproject will restore the latest version of package that you have published before build.